# Open dhcpcdui from commandline

Tags: raspbian

Hy

I need to open **dhcpcdui** (the gui to config Network connections) from commandline.

When typing "*dhcpcdui*" i get "*command not found*"

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The program is called `dhcpcd-gtk`. The package [dhcpcd-gtk](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dhcpcd-gtk) needs to be installed for that (but is installed by default unless you're using Raspbian Lite).

Comment: Im Sorry,
But when I type 'dhcpcd-gtk' in the terminal, it does not open.

Comment: @ThomasKrcal Perhaps it gives an error message?

Comment: Yes, there is the error message "command not found"

Comment: Please check first if the `dhcpcd-gtk` package is installed at all, either with `dpkg -l dhcpcd-gtk` or with `apt-cache policy dhcpcd-gtk`.